# MySQL - Select multiple values across multiple columns where all matches have a result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to construct a query that will allow me to "filter" on pairs of columns for particular criteria. I need to be able to construct multiple filters for the same given pair. The end result should only return instances that have data for the case where all filters are applied.

I constructed a trivial example demonstrating what I would like to be able to do.

Using the follow table definition:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `foo` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Index` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Header` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC));

INSERT INTO `foo` (`Index`, `Header`, `Value`)
VALUES
    (0, 'Header_1', 'a'),
    (0, 'Header_2', 'b'),
    (1, 'Header_1', 'a'),
    (1, 'Header_2', 'c');
```

I would like a query that would return the following, given that you are looking for the case where 'Header_1' == 'a' and 'header_2' == 'b':

```
Index | Header   | Value
------------------------
0     | Header_1 | a
0     | Header_2 | b
```

My current attempt is as follows:

```
SELECT `Index`, `Header`, `Value` FROM `foo`
    WHERE (
            (`Header` = 'Header_1') AND (`Value` = 'a')
        OR (
            (`Header` = 'Header_2') AND (`Value` = 'b')
        )
    )
GROUP BY `Header`, `Value`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Index`) = 2
ORDER BY `Index`, `Header`;
```

That code returns the following:

```
Index | Header   | Value
------------------------
0     | Header_1 | a
```

I am missing one of my return rows. How can I restructure the query to return all of the matching rows?

Note that I declared the table as a temporary table. This is important, as I am working with temporary tables, and they have special restrictions to keep in mind (namely not being able to open it more than once in the same statement).

Comment: So what's the issue? Does it not work for you? If not, why not?

Comment: So to summarize: given a set of filter specifications, where each filter consists of multiple values: If at least one row is found matching each of the filters, then return all rows that match all filters.  Is this correct?  Or, to paraphrase for one dimension: given a set of keys, if there exists at least one row matching every distinct key, return the union of all rows matching all keys.

Comment: @Jim: My bad, I completely forgot to ask my actual question.... See the update. Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Your problem is the limitation on temp tables in MySQL. I had no idea MySQL had such a problem.  This would be trivially easy in Oracle or Postgres.  I can't come up with a way to accomplish this without a self-join or correlated subquery on the same table.  You may be forced to create a real table.

Comment: Yeah, it can be quite frustrating at times. Without that limitation, I would use a sub-query to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns only header_1 because the clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Index`) = 2
```

is only correct for Header_1.

Header_2 has count=1, therefore removed from the end result.

To get a clearer picture of what i say use:

```
SELECT `Index`, `Header`, `Value`, COUNT(DISTINCT `Index`) FROM `foo`
    WHERE (
            (`Header` = 'Header_1') AND (`Value` = 'a')
        OR (
            (`Header` = 'Header_2') AND (`Value` = 'b')
        )
    )
GROUP BY `Header`, `Value`
ORDER BY `Index`, `Header`;
```

and take a look at the last column.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I should have realized that was the issue. I'm still not sure how to make the query do what I want it to, but at least I know what my current problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do this with only the one temporary table. I'm not happy with this result, but at least it works.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `foo2`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `foo2` (
    SELECT `Index` FROM `foo`
        WHERE (
            (`Header` = 'Header_1') AND (`Value` = 'a')
        OR (
            (`Header` = 'Header_2') AND (`Value` = 'b')
        )
    )
    GROUP BY `Index`
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Header`) = 2
);

SELECT DISTINCT t1.`Index`, t1.`Header`, t1.`Value` FROM `foo` t1
INNER JOIN `foo2` t2 ON t2.`Index` = t1.`Index`
ORDER BY t1.`Index`, t1.`Header`;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
SELECT `index` 
  FROM foo 
 WHERE (header,value) IN (('header_1','a')) 
    OR (header,value) IN (('header_2','b')) 
 GROUP 
    BY `index` 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: This is very similar to the code I had before and suffers similar issues. It can be used to find the `Index` but not the desired `Index, Header, Value`.

Comment: Yes, but I specifically need to know which Index aligns to which Header-Value pair. Just having the Indexes is not useful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand what you mean. Is there additional information in the table missing from your DDLs?

Comment: Yes. This is just a basic example of a much larger system. The real table is much larger, has more columns, and is being used in a rather large join with a number of other tables. I didn't want to get into all of it, so I just limited my question to the particular portion of the query that I was having troubles with.

It's also important to keep in mind that in many cases I may not know all of the header-value pairs. This code is dynamic, so the operator for `Value` can change, and if it isn't `=` or something similar, I will not know the actual header-value pairs.